# Debugging NDK library in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, genymotion

I have two projects in my Eclipse workspace - one is an Android library, which includes a native library, and the other is a test app that includes that Android library (and by extension the native library).

I plan to make another "real" app based on the library, so I'd like to keep these separated into two projects.

My problem is that I can't break or step into the native code - I can only step over it and use LogCat output. How can I enable full debugging in my native library?

Considerations:

1. I am using the [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) emulator, not the default one
2. I have installed the [ARM translation package](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) on my emulated device
3. I am using a Mac (if that makes a difference)
4. I have installed the [ARM DS-5 debugging package](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/android-debug-session-tutorial/) but couldn't get it to work

Comment: Hi, did you get it to work? I'm facing similar problems... :(